# Different VF email templates trigged by picklist value?

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I am slowly loosing the will to live at the moment, and I don’t know whether I am over complication the situation or not.

Currently I have an object called “Certificates” Which sits on the contact and is only used by one profile “Retail”

There are currently two record types ;
CPD Certificate
Certificate of Attendance

Dependent on the record type you choose, you are generated with an email template.

Now I don’t want to create a separate record type for a new profile to use the object.  I want to use the existing record type, but identify which profile within the record type, and generate the email from there.

To do this I have created a picklist field called “team” and I have the following two values ;
Retail
Institutional

If the user selects “Retail” I want the existing email template to be sent out

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="{!relatedTo.Date__c} {!relatedTo.RecordType.Name} {!relatedTo.Name}" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Certificate__c">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <p>Dear {!recipient.FirstName},</p>
    <p>Please find attached your {!relatedTo.RecordType.Name} for the event you attended on&nbsp;<c:DisplayFormattedDate date_time_value="{!relatedTo.Date__c}" date_time_format="EEE MMM d kk:mm:ss z yyyy"/>.</p>
    <p>Kind Regards,</p>
    <p>{!recipient.Owner.Name}</p>
    <hr />        
    <c:Attendance_Certificate Certificate="{!relatedTo}" />
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
    Dear {!recipient.FirstName},
    Please find attached your {!relatedTo.RecordType.Name} for the event you attended on {!day(relatedTo.Date__c)}/{!month(relatedTo.Date__c)}/{!year(relatedTo.Date__c)}
    Kind Regards,
    {!recipient.Owner.Name}
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
<messaging:attachment renderAs="PDF" filename="{!relatedTo.RecordType.Name}_{!relatedTo.Name}.pdf">
    <html>
        <body>
            <c:Attendance_Certificate Certificate="{!relatedTo}"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</messaging:attachment>
```

however if they select “Institutional” a new email template is generated.
also how can i amend the details within the PDF ? as for the new Institutional email template, there is a different MD, And registration number etc

Looking forward to your help

KR 
D

Comment: I think we're missing some details about your process. What triggers the email send? Is it a workflow rule, trigger, or user action (like a button or custom link)? Is the WFR/trigger/button on the Contact or the Certificate?

Comment: HI Thomas, 

Its a button. 
Label : Send Certificate

Button or link url : /_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?&p2_lkid={!Certificate__c.AttendeeId__c}&p3={!Certificate__c.Name}&p3_lkid={!Certificate__c.Id}&template_id=00X50000001UlL9&p5=&retURL=/{!Certificate__c.Id}&new_template=1

Answer (score 1):

OK - so you are URL hacking the send an email form from a button, and, if I understand correctly, you want to dynamically set the templateId based on the value of custom field team__c

If so, then your URL hack can be done as follows (I used line breaks for readability; URLs cant have line breaks of course):

Note the use of the function `IF` to do dynamic construction

```
 /_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?&p2_lkid={!Certificate__c.AttendeeId__c}
&p3={!C‌​ertificate__c.Name}
&p3_lkid={!Certificate__c.Id}
&template_id={!IF(ISPICKVAL(Certificate__c.team__c,"Retail"),"theretailtemplateId","theInstitutionalTemplateId")}
&p5=&re‌​tURL=/{!Certificate__c.Id}&new_template=1
```

To make the PDF different for Retail vs Institutional, your custom component `Attendance_Certificate` will need its own custom controller.  The value of attribute `certificate` is passed to the custom controller by an apex:attribute in the component with an `assignTo` attribute that binds it to a custom controller property with a public setter.

Comment: HI Crop1645, 
Thank you for your response, 
With the code you have provided above, where would I put that? 
I am new to this so my apologises

Comment: @Masond3 - You said you were using a button - I presumed you meant a detail page button or link; if so, then the value above is what goes into the `url` field on the button configuration screen